# Is there a way to only validate input during insertion using Objectionjs and not during update?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, knex.js, objection.js

```
const BaseModel = require("./base_model.js");

class CustomerModel extends BaseModel {

  static get tableName() {
    return "customers";
  }

  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: "object", required: ['name','phone_number','email'],

      properties: {
        id: { type: "string" },
        name: { type: ["string", "null"], maxLength: 150 },
        phone_number: { type: ["string", "null"] },
        email: { type: ["string", "null"], maxLength: 150 },
        website: { type: ["string", "null"], maxLength: 150 },
        address: { type: ["string", "null"], maxLength: 150 },
        customer_type: { "type": "string" },
        version: { type: ["integer"] },
        synced_at: { "type": ["string", "null"] },
        created_at: { "type": "string" },
        updated_at: { "type": "string" }
      }
    };
  }

  get itemVersion() {
    return false;
  }
}

module.exports = CustomerModel;
```

I don't want validation to occur when I update the model

Answer (score 1):

[to ignore validation use `patch`,](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/mutate-methods.html#update) `update` will validate as if it was an `insert` and validated against schema

Comment: That works well, I don't know how I overlooked that instruction on the documentation, appreciate for pointing out this